# Definition List not working in Wordpress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, html

As a Wordpress newbie, I am currently throwing together a template based off links from around the net that will display all of my blog posts on a single page grouped by the categories they are in. Unfortunately, no matter how I tinker with the definition lists, the formatting doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone see why the following code is not responsive to my DL? The link to the actual page is http://gameservertutorials.com/?page_id=2

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Group Archives
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

    <?php

        $cat_args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'child_of' => 0
        );

        $categories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

    ?>

    <div class="post">

    <dl>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category){ ?>

                <div class="title">
                        <dt><h2><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>" title="<?php echo sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name ?></a></h2></dt>
                </div>

                <?php
                    $post_args = array(
                        'numberposts' => 50,
                        'category' => $category->term_id
                    );

                    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

                    foreach($posts as $post){
                ?>

                <dd><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></dd>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </dl>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the surrounding DIVs from the `<dt>` tags:

```
 <dt class="title"><h2><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>" title="<?php echo sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name ?></a></h2></dt>
```

Comment: No luck on that, didn't change anything.